# Codeception code coverage - file_get_contents exception (c3/report/clear)

Tags: php, phpunit, codeception

I'm using **[Codeception](http://codeception.com/)** with **[Laravel 4](http://laravel.com/)**. In particular I'm trying to use **[remote code coverage](http://codeception.com/docs/11-CodeCoverage)** so that I can include acceptance testing in the code coverage results.

XDebug with remote_enable are configured, and **[c3.php](https://github.com/Codeception/c3)** is installed and included in 'public/index.php'.

On Windows everything works as expected. But on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (with PHP5.4) I get this exception:

```
 [ErrorException] file_get_contents(http://localhost/c3/report/clear): 
 failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to take a look into the error log of your webserver, a 500 error most often is a sign for that. Also take care you're logging PHP errors on the server and check that error log there, too.

Comment: @hakre thanks. I had an error in the path when including c3.php.

Comment: Yes 500 errors can be a lot of things so one needs to check logs. Just by the error code it's hard to tell. Probably add that as an answer so that it's documented in case someone else has a similar issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was easy to fix. There was an error in the path when including c3.php from index.php. The Apache error log made this clear.

Comment: I have a different issue, but looking in the apache log was something I hadn't thought of.  +1